# How to implement tokenizer.rbegin() and rend() for boost::tokenizer?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm playing around with boost::tokenizer however I realize that it does not support rbegin() and rend(). I would like to ask how can I add these two functions to the existing class?

This is from the boost site:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main() {
 string str( "12/12/1986" );
 typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokenizer;
 boost::char_separator<char> sep( "/" );
 tokenizer tokens( str, sep );
 cout << *tokens.begin() << endl;
    // cout << *tokens.rbegin() << endl; How could I implement this?
 return 0;
}
```

**Update**
This is my current progress. I first navigate to the src of tokenizer:

```
//===========================================================================
  // A container-view of a tokenized "sequence"
  template <
    typename TokenizerFunc = char_delimiters_separator<char>, 
    typename Iterator = std::string::const_iterator,
    typename Type = std::string
  >
  class tokenizer {
  private:
    typedef token_iterator_generator<TokenizerFunc,Iterator,Type> TGen;

    // It seems that MSVC does not like the unqualified use of iterator,
    // Thus we use iter internally when it is used unqualified and
    // the users of this class will always qualify iterator.     
    typedef typename TGen::type iter;

  public:

    typedef iter iterator;
    typedef iter const_iterator;
    typedef Type value_type;
    typedef value_type& reference;
    typedef const value_type& const_reference;
    typedef value_type* pointer;
    typedef const pointer const_pointer;
    typedef void size_type;
    typedef void difference_type;

    tokenizer(Iterator first, Iterator last,
              const TokenizerFunc& f = TokenizerFunc()) 
      : first_(first), last_(last), f_(f) { }

    template <typename Container>
    tokenizer(const Container& c)
      : first_(c.begin()), last_(c.end()), f_() { }

    template <typename Container>
    tokenizer(const Container& c,const TokenizerFunc& f)
      : first_(c.begin()), last_(c.end()), f_(f) { }

    void assign(Iterator first, Iterator last){
      first_ = first;
      last_ = last;
    }

    void assign(Iterator first, Iterator last, const TokenizerFunc& f){
      assign(first,last);
      f_ = f;
    }

    template <typename Container>
    void assign(const Container& c){
      assign(c.begin(),c.end());
    }


    template <typename Container>
    void assign(const Container& c, const TokenizerFunc& f){
      assign(c.begin(),c.end(),f);
    }

    iter begin() const { return iter(f_,first_,last_); }
    iter end() const { return iter(f_,last_,last_); }

  private:
    Iterator first_;
    Iterator last_;
    TokenizerFunc f_;
  };
```

Then I focus on the two methods:

```
iter begin() const { return iter(f_,first_,last_); }
iter end() const { return iter(f_,last_,last_); }
```

since it returns a constructor of type iter( f_, first_, last_ ), I then move to the source of this class. And iter is actually:

```
 typedef typename TGen::type iter;
```

which is token_iterator_generator class. And this class's implementation is:

```
template <
        class TokenizerFunc = char_delimiters_separator<char>, 
        class Iterator = std::string::const_iterator,
        class Type = std::string
    >
    class token_iterator_generator {

    private: 
    public:
        typedef token_iterator<TokenizerFunc,Iterator,Type> type;
    };
```

So now I figured out that the iterator of Tokenizer class is actually token_iterator<>. And the token_iterator's implementation really freaked me out:

```
template <class TokenizerFunc, class Iterator, class Type>
  class token_iterator
      : public iterator_facade<
            token_iterator<TokenizerFunc, Iterator, Type>
          , Type
          , typename detail::minimum_category<
                forward_traversal_tag
              , typename iterator_traversal<Iterator>::type
            >::type 
          , const Type&
        >
  {

      friend class iterator_core_access;

      TokenizerFunc f_;
      Iterator begin_;
      Iterator end_;
      bool valid_;
      Type tok_;

      void increment(){
          BOOST_ASSERT(valid_);
          valid_ = f_(begin_,end_,tok_);
      }

      const Type&  dereference() const {
          BOOST_ASSERT(valid_);
          return tok_;
      }
      template<class Other>
      bool equal(const Other& a) const{
          return (a.valid_ && valid_)
              ?( (a.begin_==begin_) && (a.end_ == end_) )
              :(a.valid_==valid_);

      }

      void initialize(){
          if(valid_) return;
          f_.reset();
          valid_ = (begin_ != end_)?
              f_(begin_,end_,tok_):false;
      }
  public:
      token_iterator():begin_(),end_(),valid_(false),tok_() { }

      token_iterator(TokenizerFunc f, Iterator begin, Iterator e = Iterator())
          : f_(f),begin_(begin),end_(e),valid_(false),tok_(){ initialize(); }

      token_iterator(Iterator begin, Iterator e = Iterator())
            : f_(),begin_(begin),end_(e),valid_(false),tok_() {initialize();}

      template<class OtherIter>
      token_iterator(
            token_iterator<TokenizerFunc, OtherIter,Type> const& t
            , typename enable_if_convertible<OtherIter, Iterator>::type* = 0)
            : f_(t.tokenizer_function()),begin_(t.base())
            ,end_(t.end()),valid_(!t.at_end()),tok_(t.current_token()) {}

      Iterator base()const{return begin_;}

      Iterator end()const{return end_;};

      TokenizerFunc tokenizer_function()const{return f_;}

      Type current_token()const{return tok_;}

      bool at_end()const{return !valid_;}




  };
```

This class is very complex, and I'm lost here :( ! The inheritance part from iterator_facade<> was so complex.
Any idea should I go next?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course make a new class that implements this by simply iterating the string using a normal tokenizer and store the values in a vector. Then implement rend and rbegin using the vector.

Simple and little risk of making an error, albeit probably not the fastest nor least memory intensive at run-time. Unless you know that this is going to be a problem this is the route I would take since it is very easy and fast to implement.

You specifically ask for extending the existing class however, which I think is a bad idea. In this case the easiest is probably to alter the constructor that takes a container (the one you are using) to instanciate an internal tokenizer object using rbegin() and rend() instead of begin() and end() for the container. To implement your own rbegin() and rend() start off with the iterators you get from begin and end from the internal tokenizer. The tokens returned from these are probably going to be backwards though, so you would need to reverse those. The actual iterator type would probably be pretty easy to implement using the boost::iterators package though.

Note that you would need to take special care for the constructors that take explicit iterators, or decide only to implement a subset of the class' functionality for your reverse iterators (in which case you should probably use a separate class that keeps two internal tokenizers anyway instead of pretending to be a boost::tokenizer).

The alternative to this is to alter the char_separator (and the other separator classes) so that you can explicitly specify which specialization of the tokenizer_detail::assign_or_plus_equal so that you can add each char at the beginning of each partial string instead of the end.

Hope this helps. I would go for the first alternative or just simply change my requirements so that I don't need the reverse iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this (from [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm))

> The tokenizer class provides a container view of a series of tokens contained in a sequence. You set the sequence to parse and the TokenizerFunction to use to parse the sequence either upon construction or using the assign member function. Note: No parsing is actually done upon construction. Parsing is done on demand as the tokens are accessed via the iterator provided by begin.

I'd say you can almost copy paste the code, but starting at str[strlen(str)-1] and going until 0. However, you first have to create a typedef named *reverse_iterator* and really parse the tokens on demand as the reverse iterator goes to the beginning of the string. Do not hesitate to show your progress and ask questions while you do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [boost::algorithm::split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id1155181.html)

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>

std::string str("12/12/1986");
std::vector<std::string> results;

boost::algorithm::split(results, str, boost::algorithm::is_any_of("/"));
```

(see [Boost String Algorithms Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id1155181.html))

So you can easily iterate over the resulting std::vector with rbegin() and rend().